# How to change the airthmetic operator precedence in java?

Tags: java, operators, operator-precedence

We all know that `/` has higher precedence followed by `*` , `%` , `+` , `-`

So, `2 + 3 * 5` = 17

But I want to modify the operator precedence, say like - has highest precedence followed by `+` , `%` , `*` , `/`

So, `2 + 3 * 5` = 25

Comment: You can't. You can add brackets, but not change fundamental mathematical rules.

Comment: That's what parenthesis `(` are usefull for, you can't change operator precedence.

Comment: You cannot modify operator precedence.

Comment: BTW how do you get 15, I thought it was 25

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the operator precedence but you can use parenthesis instead.
Use parenthesis to do that -

(2+3)*5 -> 5 * 5 -> 25

The addition will take place first(since in parentheses), followed by the multiplication.

Comment: Done. Thanks @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 1):

> How to change the arithmetic operator precedence in java?

You can't change them individually, but with a pair of brackets. It can operate on the in the order you want.

Example:

```
(2 + 3) * 5 % 2     //I want + first
(2 + 3) * (5 % 2)   //I want + first followed by %
```

Note that it will still be operating from left to right

> We all know that / has higher precedence followed by * , % , + , -

This is not true. `/`, `*` and `&` has the same precedence and `+` and `-` has the same precedence. All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right. Assignment operators are evaluated right to left.

You can take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), it will be clear.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Woops, typed wrongly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
(2 + 3) * 5 = 25; //5 * 5 = 25
```

The sum will be executed before the multiplication.